# How to override Kendo React Styles?

Tags: spfx, kendo-react-ui

I am working on SPFx with React and I used a Kendo Panel Bar as given- **https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/layout/panelbar/**

I wanted to override the Panel Item's header CSS like this-

```
.k-panelbar>.k-item>.k-link {
    color: black;
    font-size:large;
    font-weight: bolder;
    background-color: pink;
}
```

This works fine while working on Stackblitz but not in my SPFx solution's module.scss file. What am I doing wrong?